# How do I group by values in multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, group-by, sum

Imagine a table that looks like [image: this:]

| `sender_ID` | `Receiver_ID` | `message_ID` | , say table name is `**tb**` now I want to write an SQL query that gives me :
`user_id`, `Total messages exchanged by that user` . So basically if id = 12 sent 3 messages and received 5 messages, the result will be: 12, 8

I'm not sure if

```
Select COUNT(MESSAGE_ID)
from tb
group by sender_id, reciever_id
```

but this is clearly wrong

Comment: Please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, then do what explained there

Comment: select user_id, count(message_id) from tb where user_id = 12 group by user_id

Comment: @GotStu There's no `user_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` to synthesize a table of all the senders and receivers in one column. Then you can join that with `tb` to count both IDs.

```
WITH users AS (
    SELECT sender_id AS id
    FROM tb
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT receiver_id AS id
    FROM tb
)
SELECT u.id, COUNT(*) AS message_count
FROM users u
JOIN tb ON u.id IN (tb.sender_id, tb.receiver_id)
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This version, also using a CTE to create a single column of users_ids, has just two table scans.

```
with cte as (
  select sender_id as user_id, message_id 
  from tb
  union
  select receiver_id, message_id
  from tb
  )
select user_id, count(message_id) as messages
from cte
group by user_id
order by user_id;
```

| user_id | messages |
| --- | --- |
| 3601 | 4 |
| 4500 | 3 |
| 8752 | 1 |

---